# Drupal 7 how to use item menu as MENU_LOCAL_TASK and MENU_NORMAL_ITEM simultaneous?

Tags: 7, navigation

I have hook_menu with 3 pages they are defined by default as MENU_NORMAL_ITEMs and I see them from in main menu:
[image]

```
$items['accounting'] = [
    'title' => 'Accounting',
    'page callback' => 'accounting_extras_unprocessed_page',
    'access arguments' => ['access accounting extras'],
    'file' => 'accounting.pages.inc',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'weight' => 10,
  ];

  $items['accounting/extras'] = [
    'title'   => 'Extras',
    'page callback' => 'accounting_extras_unprocessed_page',
    'access arguments' => ['access accounting extras'],
    'file' => 'accounting.pages.inc',
    'weight'  => 0,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
  ];

  $items['accounting/report'] = [
    'title'            => 'Report',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => ['accounting_report_form', 'report'],
    'access arguments' => ['access accounting report'],
    'file'             => 'forms/accounting_report.inc',
    'weight'           => 1,
    'menu_name'        => 'main-menu',
  ];

  $items['accounting/transfer'] = [
    'title'            => 'Internal transactions',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => ['accounting_report_form', 'transfer'],
    'access arguments' => ['access accounting report'],
    'file'             => 'forms/accounting_report.inc',
    'weight'           => 2,
    'menu_name'        => 'main-menu',
  ];
```

But I also need to see them as MENU_LOCAL_TASK and if I add `type = MENU_LOCAL_TASK` then they disappear from menu and appear as local tasks
[image]

What to do to see them in both places? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bitwise operator for that, e.g.

```
MENU_LOCAL_TASK | MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
```

There's a real-world example in the core comment module ([`comment_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_menu/7.x)):

```
$items['admin/content/comment'] = array(
  'title' => 'Comments',
  'description' => 'List and edit site comments and the comment approval queue.',
  'page callback' => 'comment_admin',
  'access arguments' => array('administer comments'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK | MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'file' => 'comment.admin.inc',
);
```

Comment: that solved my problem thank you, could you please explain or give a reference to these bitwise operators because it's something new for me.

Comment: It's a binary (bit masking) thing; details of PHP's implementation are [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), but a good portion of languages have an equivalent